# How to say 上蹿下跳 in English?

Tags: idioms

I am learning Chinese idioms.

How to say 上蹿下跳 in English? help me

Comment: see online dictionaries, e.g. bkrs:(1) [jump]∶[动物]到处蹿跳, 到处蹿蹦
小松鼠上蹿下跳, 寻找食物
[jukuu:1.  For a while the ship kept bucking and sidling like a vicious horse, the sails filling, now on one tack, now on another, and the boom swinging to and fro till the mast groaned aloud under the strain.
 有那么一会儿，帆船像匹烈马那样不停地上蹿下跳，左摇右晃； 鼓起的风帆时而这边受风，时而那边受风； 帆杠来回晃动，拖得主桅不停地叫唤。]
 

(2) [run around on sinister errands]∶比喻人上下奔走, 四处活动(含贬义)
一有机会, 他就上蹿下跳, 煽风点火

Comment: How about `jump up and down`? [上蹿下跳](http://www.zdic.net/c/a/163/360618.htm), (1) [jump] (2) [run around on sinister errands].

Answer (score 1):

`run around on sinister errands`, the only one right answer, can not be used in other scene. It's a term of abuse, I'm chinese, trust me.

Answer (score 0):

`cavort` is more accurate I think. You can also use `coltish`

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but I don't think demotic is the right word there: It is much less popular than these alternatives: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=demotic%2Cvulgar%2Cvernacular%2Ccolloquial&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdemotic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvulgar%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvernacular%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccolloquial%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @ColinZwanziger pardon my usage

Answer (score -1):

Jumping up and down should be good!